# Show pagination number of post in single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to make a "backwards" link back to the parent category from displayed post. 
I've accomplished it this way:

```
$cats=get_the_category();
 foreach($cats as $cat){
  if($cat->category_parent == 0 && $cat->term_id != 1){
    echo '<h2 class="link"><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->term_id ).'">Return</a></h2>';
  }
    break;
 }
```

But this solution doesn't work exactly as I need, I would like to redirect user to exact previous page not only to the first page of category. But im unable to find way how to get this information from content-single.php, i dont want to use HTTP referer or any javascript, just pure wordpress solution. Maybe somehow calculate posts per page, and if posts exceeds that limit then it can be considered like another page?

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried `previous_posts(false)` ? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_posts/